# Font {Times} on personalized contents [error]

Tags: table-of-contents, times

I'm trying to change the style of the Table of contents The following commands let the Table of contents in the desired style. But when I use `\usepackage{times}` to use the font Times New Roman, the numbering of the sections of Table of contents is centralized. What can I do to make the numbering not be centered?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titletoc}
%\usepackage{times}

% \dottedcontents{<section>}[<left>]{<above-code>}
% {<label width>}{<leader width>}
\dottedcontents{section}[0em]{\bfseries}{2.9em}{1pc}
\dottedcontents{subsection}[0em]{}{3.3em}{1pc}

% center the toc heading
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centering Contents}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\section{Test section one}
\subsection{Test subsection}


\section{Test section two}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: After I posted I saw had gone wrong =\ . Thx Egreg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the same `labelwidth` for both section and subsection:

```
\dottedcontents{section}[0em]{\bfseries}{3.3em}{1pc}
\dottedcontents{subsection}[0em]{}{3.3em}{1pc}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{times}

% \dottedcontents{<section>}[<left>]{<above-code>}
% {<label width>}{<leader width>}
\dottedcontents{section}[0em]{\bfseries}{3.3em}{1pc}
\dottedcontents{subsection}[0em]{}{3.3em}{1pc}

% center the toc heading
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centering Contents}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\section{Test section one}
\subsection{Test subsection}


\section{Test section two}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW don't use `times` (doesn't support math), but use newer `newtx` family or  similar fonts.

Comment: I'm new to LaTeX, and even beginner. Thanks for the tip, now I changed for NEWTEX font. But I could not get the numbering the table of contents =\

Comment: @Freitas Use `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`. Do you get it right when you run my code as such?

Comment: Now I understand the parameters that had explained to me, it worked. Sorry for my ignorance =) Thank you so much  for the help Professor Harish Kumar.

Comment: p.s Sorry for my english

Comment: @Freitas Glad you could make it. :) All the best using LaTeX.